# How to organize data sequences?

Tags: python, database, decimal

Please help me with a python solution to this problem. Thanks for the reply that i need to edit and be concise.

Lets say i have a data of numbers like this

1.2, 1.3 , 1.4, 1.5, 1.6

I want to write a python code that takes decimal number as input. Once executed, it saves the input at the beginning of the sequence and deletes the last number om the sequence e.g say i enter 1.9 into the python prompt.
It becomes like this : 1.9, 1.2,1.3, 1.4, 1.5

If i enter another number e.g 4.2, it becomes

4.2, 1.9,1.2, 1.3, 1.4

Thats my first question.

Comment: Please post minimal reproducible example, explaining just the bare minimum. If you are posting such long explanation, please post TLDR as well. There is quite a good chance you won't get answer quickly as no one likes to read such long paragraphs

Comment: Hi. Suggest rephase your question and extract a small sub-problem from the larger problem. You will more likely get answers, Include code showing what have you tried so far and what is not working with it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you miss 1.2? The first output may be 1.9, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5?

Comment: Sorry i missed 1.2.

Comment: You’re looking for a ‘queue’ (FIFO) data structure. These can be implemented in Python using a `list`. Perhaps do a bit of research using these specifics.